# Swift:Change System Cursor

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage, nscursor

I created a simple macos app project in Swift.
The app changes the NSCursor image with a custom image.
This works fine but as soon as I click on a different app, e.g. Safari,
macos restores the default system cursor.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? My goal is to keep the custom cursor for as long as my app is running and not only when it's focused.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write an OS X application that can effect changes (custom cursor, draw an image) even when it is not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975703/how-to-write-an-os-x-application-that-can-effect-changes-custom-cursor-draw-an)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It does not actually answer my question how I hoped, but I do know now that I have to be creative to solve it, because the macos API does not provide this feature. Unfortunately, the suggestion with the borderless window and editing its level does not solve my problem either.